# Is there a way to print page count with CUPS?

Tags: node.js, printing, ubuntu-18.04, cups

I'm trying to add a counter when printing images(labels) with CUPS.

For example:
I have an image file that i have to print 1000 times.
Each image needs to have a counter at the bottom right(1-1000 or 1,2,3...).

is this possible to achieve with CUPS? if cant be done with CUPS, how would you approach this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The footer option is [not supported](https://github.com/apple/cups/issues/5073) by cups.

You can try using OpenCV to add page number text at the bottom of the image and print the new image.

Comment: hmm I looked around and found te4cups but it does not help me to add some sort of counter. I'm still looking for a way.

Comment: @AndreMendes Can you share the link of te4cups ?